# Check if windows account password is set allowed to expire in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, boolean, wmic

I have looked high and low for a way to check the local user manager settings for a local account's password policy. Essentially I just want my app to tell me immediately if the current user accounts password is set to expire by saying "pass" or "fail" in a textbox. I have checked WMIC and a few other references and haven't found anything of any worth. Any thoughts?

EDIT: I went a slightly different route and called to CMD in the background with administrative privileges`string domainName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\').First(); ;
                dName.Text = domainName;

```
            string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\').Last(); ;
            user.Text = userName;

            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c net user" + " " + user.Text;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            cmd.Start();
            //* Read the output (or the error)
            string output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            RtextBox2.Text = output;
            cmd.WaitForExit();


            // Check string for specific value of "Password expires             Never" if NOT present, pass the client. If PRESENT Fail the client. Override in next section below. 
            if (RtextBox2.Text.Contains("Password expires             Never") == false)
            {
                pwexpire.Text = "PASS";
            }
            else
            {
                pwexpire.Text = "FAIL";
            }`.
```

Comment: I have answered my own question but the system wont allow me to mark it as answered. I would like to complete this so that others can see how i accomplished hat I had described.

Answer (score 1):

WMIC is the command-line for WMI, I'm not sure why you went down that path.

Most of Windows' authentication system is controllable via ADSI, not WMI.

For LDAP (Active Directory) accounts, here is the canonical white paper: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323750/ (it's in VBScript, but trivially reworkable for C#).

For local accounts, I don't think you can get the expiry date, but you can check the `userFlags` option to see if there is an expiry requirement enabled.

Apparently in .NET 3.5 Microsoft added `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` which makes this easier:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

// create a machine-context (local machine)
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Machine );

UserPrincipal user =
    UserPrincipal.Current;
    // Or use `FindByIdentity` if you want to manually specify a user.
    // UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( ctx, IdentityType.Sid, <YourSidHere> );

if( user != null ) {

    Console.WriteLine("Password expires: {0}", !user.PasswordNeverExpires );
}
```

This is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx